# Passing string from DataBinding in to custom view xml attribute

Tags: android, android-databinding, declare-styleable

I have situation where want to pass string in to custom view attribute, but it not working if not passing only a reference.

Working:

```
......
app:title="sa"
app:title="@string/winning_title"
......
```

Not working:

```
  <data>

        <variable
            name="title"
            type="String" />
    </data>
......

   app:title="@{title}"
```

And stylable:

```
   <declare-styleable name="CollapsibleRecyclerView">
        <attr name="title" format="string"/>
        <attr name="separatorsColor" format="color"/>
        <attr name="animationDuration" format="integer"/>
    </declare-styleable>
```

Any ideas how to fix it?

Answer (score 1):

Since you used "@{...}", I believe Android will automatically attempt to use data binding on it and look for a corresponding custom BindingAdapter.

You could define something like this and see if it works:

```
@BindingAdapter("app:title")
public static void setPaddingLeft(YourView view, String text) {
  view.doSomething(text);
}
```